# Predictive curve fitting matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, curve-fitting, prediction, least-squares

I have a question about curve fitting, I have many curves like the one in the picture.

X axis : time
Y axis : temperature

Each sample comes out every 30s.

GOAL : predict the value at the end of the transient

What would you do in this situation?
What I am doing is this :
for every new sample I start a new fitting (and so each fitting is independent  from the previous one) and check the value of the fitted curve 2 hours (all curves I have set before 2h) after the start of the measurement. If for a number (let's say 5) of subsequent fitting the value in the future stays more or less the same(+-0.2°C) I so assume that the estimation is the right one.

This approach seems to me far too simple and I think I am not exploiting all information. For example the info of the error I am making punctually (e.g. at minute 4:00 I predict and at 4:30 I see that I am doing an error).

[image]

In the picture the red part of the curve is excluded (but the real data in the future passes through it). the estimation is the blue one. You see in this case I don't have a good prediction... In general I have also more flat curves.

Comment: Do you know the dynamics of your system? Using them can drastically improve the performance of your estimation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
What do you mean by dynamics? Like the time constant of this system? 
The curves show the heating of different objects which may have a very different behaviour. Some may be big and so take much time(sort of big equivalent RC time constant) to reach steady state, others instead may heat up more quickly.
What is your suggestion?
Anyway sorry if I misunterstood... be patient, I am a beginner :)

Comment: Yes, thing like time constants. Probably a better fitting function is something like `1-e^(-t/tau)`, where `tau` is the parameter that you try to estimate based on your previous measured points.

Comment: Yes in principle it should be. I've tried in matlab exp2 and also the function you wrote.
However I have seen that the rational 4vs4 works better in this case.
When I use only a partial set of data to do a prediction the exponential drifts('goes too high') while rat44 is 'more slow' and so better for my case.

Comment: It's strange that a polynomial gives a better extrapolation, because your data really looks like an exponential function and polynomial fits often give strange results outside the fitting region. If you use all the data, is the exponential function able to fit the data points well? If not, you should extend the function. Perhaps you can upload some test data/code?

Comment: Yes if I give all the points also the exp2 works well (sometimes even better). With rat44 is true that sometimes I obtain strange results (such as vertical asymptote) but it happens very seldom. In general as I said the rat44 predicts better the steady value.
Anyway my problem is not a single fitting but a prediction. Do you think that what I am doing is reasonable? My question is mainly about the general procedure to undertake and if it is possibile to build a model that can learn from the errors is doing on partial estimations. (the thing about min 4 and 4:30)

Comment: I think your are using a good basic procedure. Using the error (eg. correcting for the extrapolated error) may be possible, but is tricky and may not always give good results. Training a neural network to perform the estimation is probably overkill. The easiest solution is to determine a good parametric form of your response function, which include all dominant dynamics, but without to many degrees of freedom, otherwise you will [overfit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) your problem. Maybe someone else knows a better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I have tried the exponential limiting the parameters in an interval and I have better results.
You mentioned neural networks : do you think they could give better results even if it is an exaggerated procedure in this case?
(anyway I have data not really homogeneous.. I have 370 measurements with really different time constants but they not all start from room temperature, some starts from the object already hot and they are very different... maybe this can be an issue)

Comment: Neural networks could perform better, but you need a lot of training data which should be representative for the data for which you will use the neural network later on. Note that I am not an expert in neural networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Based on the comments above, I tried to formulate an answer as no one else is giving some input*.

I think your are using a good basic procedure. Better results may be obtained by using a more appropriate fitting curve, which includes all the dominant dynamics, but avoids [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) of the data. Based on your figure, the simplest form I could think of is:

```
s + a(1-e^(-t/tau))
```

with parameters `s` (the initial temperature), `a` (amplitude = steady state value) and `tau` (dominant time constant). As you mentioned yourself, limiting the allowed range for the parameters may avoid overfitting and increase the quality of your estimation.

Using a random high order function, like you are using now, may give good interpolation results, but are dangerous to use for extrapolation, because strange effects may occur outside the fitting region.

**Alternatives**

*Using the error* (eg. correcting for the extrapolated error) may be possible, but is tricky and may not always give good results.

Training a *neural network* to perform the estimation is probably overkill, but may give better results if applied correctly. Note that you need a lot of training data which should be representative for the data for which you will use the neural network later on.